# How to add song to playlist program using classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, class, playlist

I'm trying to fix my "addSongtoPlaylist" function. As of right now it's not working, I'm not sure if my statement is wrong in the function, but I'm kind of stuck on that part right now. This program uses GUI to create a playlist from a song list. I'm supposed to be able to load the song list, add, delete, and play the songs in the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated for that one function.

```
#include "globals.h"  //some global variables are included here
#include <cstdlib>  //standard c library
#include "mediaItem.h"  //the mediaItem class  (you need to write a class that extends this class)
#include "song.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


ifstream infile;
song mySong[MAX_SONGS];
int NumberOfSongs;
int myPlaylist[MAX_PLAYLIST];
int PlaylistSize; //counter for size of playlist in array
song *newPlaylist[MAX_PLAYLIST];

bool loadSongList(string filename)
{
    infile.open(filename);
    string tempArtist, tempTitle, tempLocation;
    int i = 0;

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file could not be opened." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File opened successfully." << endl;

        infile >> NumberOfSongs;
        infile.ignore(1);

        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile, tempArtist);
            getline(infile, tempTitle);
            getline(infile, tempLocation);
            mySong[i].setArtist(tempArtist);
            mySong[i].setTitle(tempTitle);
            mySong[i].setLocation(tempLocation);

            i++;
        }
        infile.close();

        return true;
    }
}

int getNumberOfSongsInSongList()
{
    return NumberOfSongs;
}

string getSongNameFromSongList(int songNum)
{
    string tempArtist, tempTitle;

    tempArtist = mySong[songNum].getArtist();
    tempTitle = mySong[songNum].getTitle();

    return tempArtist + " - " + tempTitle;
}

string getSongNameFromPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    string tempArtist, tempTitle;

    tempArtist = mySong[myPlaylist[playlistSpot]].getArtist();
    tempTitle = mySong[myPlaylist[playlistSpot]].getTitle();

    return tempArtist + " - " + tempTitle;
}

void addSongToPlaylist(int songNum)
{
    mySong[myPlaylist[PlaylistSize]].setArtist(mySong[songNum].getArtist());
    mySong[myPlaylist[PlaylistSize]].setTitle(mySong[songNum].getTitle());
    mySong[myPlaylist[PlaylistSize]].setLocation(mySong[songNum].getLocation());

    mySong[myPlaylist[PlaylistSize]] = mySong[songNum];
    newPlaylist[PlaylistSize] = &mySong[songNum];
    PlaylistSize++;

}

int getNumberOfSongsInPlaylist()
{
    return PlaylistSize;
}

void moveSongDownInPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    int temp;
    if (playlistSpot >= PlaylistSize - 1)
        return;

    temp = myPlaylist[playlistSpot + 1];
    myPlaylist[playlistSpot + 1] = myPlaylist[playlistSpot];
    myPlaylist[playlistSpot] = temp;
}

void removeSongFromPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    for (int i = playlistSpot; i < PlaylistSize; i++)
        moveSongDownInPlaylist(i);

    myPlaylist[PlaylistSize - 1] = 0;
    PlaylistSize--;
}

void clearPlaylist()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PlaylistSize; i++)
        myPlaylist[i] = 0;

    PlaylistSize = 0;
}

void moveSongUpInPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    int temp;

    if (playlistSpot == 0)
        return;

    temp = myPlaylist[playlistSpot - 1];
    myPlaylist[playlistSpot - 1] = myPlaylist[playlistSpot];
    myPlaylist[playlistSpot] = temp;
}

void playSongFromPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    mySong[myPlaylist[playlistSpot]].playMedia();
}

void pauseSongFromPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    mySong[myPlaylist[playlistSpot]].pauseMedia();
}

void stopSongFromPlaylist(int playlistSpot)
{
    mySong[myPlaylist[playlistSpot]].stopMedia();
}
```

Comment: `"it's not working"` isn't a helpful statement. *What* isn't working? What's is supposed to be doing that it is not? Are you getting any error messages at compile-time or runtime? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Visual Studio has excellent built-in debugging facilities. If you don't know how to use them, now is the time to learn.

Comment: That's too much code to go through to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: It's supposed to add the song to a playlist in the GUI form window, my song list will load, but when I select a song and try to press the button nothing happens. I'll getting an error saying that "object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Instead of creating arrays of hardset arbitrary size, why not use `std::vector` which can be resized as needed.

Comment: My teacher wanted use to use an array of classes, and I just made infile a global while I was typing it because at first I had used it in other functions. That's really not an issue though.

Comment: I included all my code so people would be able to tell where some of the variables are coming from. There's a class called song that has all the get and set artist, title, and location functions I didn't include.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am well aware of how to use all the debugging and stepping through functions in VS. It's not exactly telling me why I'm getting this error though.

Comment: @T-Bird Then why don't you show where exactly you're getting the  `"object reference not set to an instance of an object"` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `addSongToPlaylist` function simply needs to add `songNum` to the end of `myPLaylist`.

It also looks like `myPlaylist` should just be an array of `int` not `int *`. Note: At the moment you are allocating an array of pointers, but not allocating memory for the pointers.

Each `int` in the list would be a song number referencing an existing entry in `mySong`.

My recommendation:

- Change `myPlayList` to an `int` array and fix up all the code that is dereferencing it (the `*` that are everywhere).
- Change `addSongToPLaylist` to just add the song number to the end of the array, which is denoted by the (confusingly named) `PlayListSize`.

If you have problems after that, please ask.

Edit:
As `myPlaylist` needs to be `song *myPlaylist[MAX_SONGS]`, you can still do the same as above, but rather than adding the song number to the end of the list, you would add a pointer to the song in the `mySong` array. Something like:

```
void addSongToPlaylist(int songNum)
{
    // TODO: Check PlaylistSize is less than MAX_PLAYLIST
    myPlaylist[PlaylistSize] = &mySong[songNum];
    PlaylistSize++;
}
```

Comment: The PlaylistSize was just the size of the array, I'll try this out though.

Comment: That's what I mean - `PlaylistSize` is not the size of the array. `MAX_PLAYLIST` is the size of the array. `PlaylistSize` is how much of the array you are currently using. I think it starting with a capital letter was what made it confusing. Makes it look more like a constant or `enum`.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I tried the code your way, I'm no longer getting an error, but when I press the "add song to playlist" button in the form, nothing is happening still.

Comment: How does the form know to redisplay itself with the new data? Maybe step through in the debugger to confirm that the add is happening. You did remember to increase the value of `PlaylistSize` by 1 when you add a new song?

Comment: The form knows to display with this background code our teacher wrote for the buttons/list and such. I wish he had explained it to us because we had to code around something that was already created and it didn't leave our class with hardly any room for doing the functions differently.

Comment: I figured out that I'm not supposed to be using an array of pointers for the integer though. It actually needs to be song *myPlaylist[MAX_SONGS]. However it screws up the rest of the code because its a pointer of a different type, and the add function still won't do anything with various methods I've tried.

Comment: `song *myPlaylist[MAX_SONGS]` will work, the easiest way is to make it point to entries of the `mySong` array (rather than making a fresh copy of the song object for the playlist). I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: It works to add it! But for some reason whenever you add a new song, all the previous songs become the same song.

Comment: I updated my code, I'll definitely try to fix the last duplicate issue, but I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Remove all of the lines from `addSongToPlaylist` except the last two. You don't want to be updating mySong when you are adding a song to a play list.

Comment: When I deleted those lines it would only add the first song on the list loaded no matter which one I selected.